# How do I make use of libraries in my Ember unit tests?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to make use of a library ([chance.js](http://chancejs.com/)) in my Ember unit tests, but I can't seem to import it in my tests.

So far I've tried using [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) (with and without [ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify)), [Bower](http://bower.io/) (played around with trying the `app.import` calls in `ember-cli-build.js`.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to be able to access the `chance` functions/module.

Any help would be greatly appreciate. Top marks would go to anyone who can point me to an Ember project which is using `chance.js` in their unit tests.

If possible in your answer, a brief explanation of which dependency management is appropriate would be very helpful. From what I've read, it seems NPM might be the go-to as the Ember project is looking to move away from Bower, see [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2949#issuecomment-85634073).

Also, if anyone knows of any helpful articles (up-to-date would also be a plus), feel free to mention them in comments.

Thanks!

**Edit**:
I believe some of the issues I am seeing are related to Chance using the 'anonymous' AMD module, which Ember's loader does not support. I played around a little more, but ended up going with the [ember-faker](https://github.com/johnotander/ember-faker) addon as it is supported out of the box thanks to [John Otander](https://twitter.com/4lpine).

I'll leave this question here in hopes of someone posting a wonderful answer which clarifies things :).

Comment: Do you have a github link to your project or an example project that isn't working? Most people use third party libraries with bower and app.import in ember-cli-build without issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to share my project :(.

Comment: You should try going with Bower.

Comment: the answer below doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ember CLI now supports Anonymous AMD modules](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#managing-dependencies). In your `ember-cli-build.js` file, use `app.import()` with the AMD transformation, giving the anonymous module a name like this:

```
app.import('bower_components/chance/dist/chance.min.js', {
  using: [
    { transformation: 'amd', as: 'chance' }
  ]
});
```

Then, you can import it throughout your app and tests like this:

```
import chance from 'chance';
```

Answer (score 1):

General questions:

- "... it seems NPM might be the go-to as the Ember project is looking to move away from Bower...". I've read it too and made the same conclusion.
- "which dependency management is appropriate..." I have a practice with some modules (lodash, d3, supergroup, getstream, now chance) and every time `ember-browserify` works fine.

About `chance`: looks like it works fine with `ember-browserify`.

```
//console
npm install --save-dev ember-browserify
npm install --save-dev chance

//using in application controller
import Ember from 'ember';
import Ch from 'npm:chance';

var chance = new Ch();

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  chanceString: null,
  chanceBool: chance.bool()
});

// using in application controller test
import Ch from 'npm:chance';
var chance = new Ch();

test('can use chance in tests', function(assert) {
    var controller = this.subject();
    controller.set('chanceString', chance.phone());
    assert.ok(controller.get('chanceString'));
});
```

Look at working example [here](https://github.com/artych/so_chance)

Comment: This only worked for me if the npm:chance import was included in the controller, route, etc that I was testing.  https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify/issues/14